# SQL выборочный UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Есть таблица, `T1`, в ней нужно установить значение поля `V2` в `'A3'`, но только в том случае, если это поле было равно `'A2'`. Сделать это нужно для всех записей, у которых поле `V1` равно `'A1'`

пробовал так... но что-то уже запутался...

```
UPDATE `T1` SET `V2` = REPLACE(`V2`, "A2", "A3") FROM `T1` WHERE `V1` LIKE 'A1'
```

Comment: `UPDATE T1 SET V2 = IF(V2='A2', 'A3', V2) WHERE V1='A1'`

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или я чего-то не понял, или это делается банальным запросом

```
UPDATE `T1` SET `V2` = 'A3' WHERE `V1` = 'A1' AND `V2` = 'A2'
```

Comment: я первый раз просто такое делаю, а в подсказках только запрос SELECT или UPDATE отдельно, а вот одновременно, ещё не видел примеров, а англоязычные не разобрался... спасибо

Comment: @ЮрийКрупин Так и не понял, зачем Вам `SELECT`?

Comment: просто не знал как это делается